# Using jQueryUI Sortable in post

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii

I'm using `CJuiSortable` widget to use Sortable from `jQueryUI`.

I need to use the order only when the form is submitted. However, I didn't find a way to do it using just the widget.

Does someone know if there's a way to do it?

```
$questionario->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiSortable', array(
    'id'=>'order',
    'items'=>$sortableItems,
    'itemTemplate'=>'<li id="{id}" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>{content}</li>',
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort it using update function jQueryUI (i.e) for after form submitting.

```
update: function(event, ui) {
        var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        $('#new_order').val(order.join(","));
        //alert($('#new_order').val());
}
```

Comment: In your solution is new_order a hidden field?